# MATLAB Interpolate Data more efficiently

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, concatenation, interpolation

I want to do the following in a loop so that it's more efficient:

```
data_Clim1 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,1), X, Y); 
data_Clim2 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,2), X, Y); 
data_Clim3 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,3), X, Y); 
data_Clim4 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,4), X, Y); 
data_Clim5 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,5), X, Y); 
data_Clim6 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,6), X, Y); 
data_Clim7 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,7), X, Y); 
data_Clim8 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,8), X, Y); 
data_Clim9 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,9), X, Y); 
data_Clim10 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,10), X, Y); 
data_Clim11 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,11), X, Y); 
data_Clim12 = griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,12), X, Y); 

% Add together matrices
data_Clim = [data_Clim1; data_Clim2; data_Clim3; data_Clim4; ...
    data_Clim5; data_Clim6; data_Clim7; data_Clim8; data_Clim9; ...
    data_Clim10; data_Clim11; data_Clim12]; 

% Reshape to 3D matrix
data_Clim = reshape(data_Clim, 1437, 159, 12);
```

Basically, I have a matrix that is 360x161x12 and I need to interpolate it to 1437x159x12. However, right now, using griddata, I can only interpolate one of the z dimensions at a time. Then I combine all the separate matrices (there are 12 since it's one for each month) and reshape it to the dimensions I need.

I'm assuming a while loop or a for loop would be less cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
dataClim = zeros(1437,159,12); // pre-allocation for speed
for i=1:12
  // Reshape each sub-matrix
  dataClim(:,:,i) = reshape(griddata(lonClim, latClim, ice_Clim(:,:,i), X, Y),1437,159);
end
```